# A d-ary heap problem from CLRS

Tags: data-structures, time-complexity, runtime-analysis

I got confused while solving the following problem (questions 1–3).

#### Question

> A *d*-ary heap is like a binary heap, but(with one possible exception) non-leaf nodes have *d* children instead of 2 children.
>
> 1. How would you represent a *d*-ary heap in an array?
> 2. What is the height of a *d*-ary heap of *n* elements in terms of *n* and *d*?
> 3. Give an efficient implementation of EXTRACT-MAX in a *d*-ary max-heap. Analyze its running time in terms of *d* and *n*.
> 4. <sub>Give an efficient implementation of INSERT in a *d*-ary max-heap. Analyze its running time in terms of *d* and *n*.</sub>
> 5. <sub>Give an efficient implementation of INCREASE-KEY(*A*, *i*, *k*), which flags an error if *k* < A[i] = k and then updates the *d*-ary matrix heap structure appropriately. Analyze its running time in terms of *d* and *n*.</sub>

#### My Solution

1. Give an array $A[a_1 .. a_n]$

   $\qquad \begin{align}
    \text{root} &: a_1\\
    \text{level 1} &: a_{2} \dots a_{2+d-1}\\
    \text{level 2} &: a_{2+d} \dots a_{2+d+d^2-1}\\
    &\vdots\\
    \text{level k} &: a_{2+\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k-1}d^i} \dots a_{2+\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k}d^i-1}
    \end{align}$

   → **My notation seems a bit sophisticated. Is there any other simpler one?**
2. Let *h* denotes the height of the *d*-ary heap.

   Suppose that the heap is a complete *d*-ary tree
   $$
    1+d+d^2+..+d^h=n\\
    \dfrac{d^{h+1}-1}{d-1}=n\\
    h=log_d[n{d-1}+1] - 1
    $$
3. This is my implementation:

   ```
   EXTRACT-MAX(A)
   1  if A.heapsize < 1
   2      error "heap underflow"
   3  max = A[1]
   4  A[1] = A[A.heapsize]
   5  A.heap-size = A.heap-size - 1
   6  MAX-HEAPIFY(A, 1)
   7  return max

   MAX-HEAPIFY(A, i)
   1  assign depthk-children to AUX[1..d]
   2  for k=1 to d
   3      compare A[i] with AUX[k]
   4      if A[i] <= AUX[k]
   5          exchange A[i] with AUX[k]
   6          k = largest
   7  assign AUX[1..d] back to A[depthk-children]
   8  if largest != i
   9      MAX-HEAPIFY(A, (2+(1+d+d^2+..+d^{k-1})+(largest-1) )
   ```

   - The running time of MAX-HEAPIFY:

     $$T_M = d(c_8*d + (c_9+..+c_13)*d +c_14*d)$$
     where $c_i$ denotes the cost of *i*-th line above.
   - EXTRACT-MAX:
     $$
            T_E = (c_1+..+c_7) + T_M \leq C*d*h\\
            = C*d*(log_d[n(d-1)+1] - 1)\\
            = O(dlog_d[n(d-1)])
            $$

   → **Is this an efficient solution? Or there is something wrong within my solution?**

Comment: I think there is a slight mistake in the question as well as the explanation:
The height of the d-ary heap comes to h = (log [nd − n + 1]) − 1 // NOTE its "-n" and not "-1"
and not `h = (log [nd−1+1])− 1` Thus we above explanation for height will not hold true. h = log[nd−1+1]−1 = log[nd]-1 = log[n] Although nonetheless, the height of the tree is written as `Θ(log(n)).` Note: log is always to the base d for a d-ary heap.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Your solution is valid and follows definition of *d*-ary heap. But as you pointed out your notation is a bit sophisticated.

   You might use those two following functions to retrieve parent of *i*-th element and *j*-th child of *i*-th element.

   $\text{d-ary-parent}({\it i}) \\
     \ \ \ \ {\bf return}\ \lfloor (i-2)/d + 1 \rfloor$

   $\text{d-ary-child}(i, j) \\
     \ \ \ \ {\bf return}\ d(i-1)+j+1$

   Obviously $1 \le j \le d$. You can verify those functions checking that $\text{d-ary-parent}(\text{d-ary-child}(i,j)) = i$

   Also easy to see is that binary heap is special type of $d$-ary heap where $d=2$, if you substitute $d$ with $2$, then you will see that they match functions PARENT, LEFT and RIGHT mentioned in book.
2. If I understand your answer correctly you use a [geometric progression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression). In your case you get go $h = log_d(n\,d-1+1) - 1$, which is obviously $\log_d(n\,d) - 1 = \log_d(n) + \log_d(d) - 1 = \log_d(n) + 1 - 1 = \log_d(n)$, which in fact is a valid and correct solution. But just for sake of handling constant fluctuations you might wanna write $\Theta(\log_d(n))$.

   The reason for this is that some heaps might not be balanced, so their longest path and shorthest path migt vary by some constant $c$, by using $\Theta$ notation you eliminate this problem.
3. You don't need to re-implement procedure given in textbook, but you must alter it a bit, eg assigning all children to $AUX$ table using given $\text{d-ary-parent}$ and $\text{d-ary-child}$ functions.

   Because $\text{EXTRACT-MAX}$ was not altered, it depends on running time of $\text{MAX-HEAPIFY}$. In your analysis you now you must use worst-case time proportional to hight and number of children which each node must examine (which is at most *d*). Once again your analysis is very precise, in the end you got $O(d\ \log_d(n(d-1)))$, which can be transformed to:

   $O(d\ \log_d(n(d-1))) = O(d(\log_d(n) + \log(d-1))) = O(d\ log_d(n) + d\ \log_d(d-1))$

   For practical reasons we can always assume that $d \ll n$, so we can lose the $d \log_d(d-1)$ part of *O* notation, then we will get $O(d\log_d(n))$. Which is also valid solution. But not surprisingly you can also analyse function run time using [Master theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem), which will show that $\text{MAX-HEAPIFY}$ is not only $O$ but even $\Theta$.
4. CLRS book already provides INSERT procedure.  Which looks like this:

   $\text{INSERT}(A, key)\\
     \ \ \ \ A.heap\_size = A.heap\_size + 1 \\
     \ \ \ \ A[A.heap\_size] = -\infty\\
     \ \ \ \ \text{INCREASE-KEY}(A, A.heap\_size, key)$

   It can be easy proven but common sense dictates that it's time complexity is $O(\log_d(n))$. It's because heap might be traversed all the way to the root.
5. Just like INSERT, INCREASE-KEY is also defined in textbook as:

   $\text{INCREASE-KEY}(A, i, key)\\
     \ \ \ \ {\bf if}\ key < A[i]\\
     \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ {\bf error} \text{"new key is smaller then current"}\\
     \ \ \ \ A[i] = key\\
     \ \ \ \ {\bf while}\ i > 1\ and\ A[i] > A[\text{d-ary-parent}(i)]\\
     \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ A[i] \leftrightarrow A[\text{d-ary-parent(i)}]\\
     \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ i = \text{d-ary-parent(i)}$

   Complexity is obviously $O(\log_d(n))$ (see previous point).

Comment: thanks! How about the implementation of INCREASE-KEY and INSERT? I try to write it, but it gave twice recursive call of MAX-HEAPIFY. Is there a better solution? I found little information on web and [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-ary_heap)

Comment: Is that rest of exercise? If so please update your question and I'll be happy to answer theme.

Comment: I put those question on the edited post.

Comment: reimplment the INSERT procedure? You mean, it doesn't have to call the procedure that adjusts the order within the heap, after inserting a new element? I don't get it...

Comment: That description was a bit unfortunate, see edits for clearification.

Answer (score 1):

This is not complete answer.
part b) solution is not $$h=log_d[n{d-1}+1] - 1$$
Its  $$
1+d+d^2+..+d^h=n\\
 \dfrac{d^{h+1}-1}{d-1}=n\\
 h=log_d[n(d-1)+1] - 1$$ as pointed out by user 55463(because he cant comment,but answer),but downvoted because of lack of explanation.
Upvoted answer has also mistakenly solved it. 
Answer will still be $$h=\Theta(\log_d(n))$$
Source:[Problem 2-2. Analysis of d
-ary heaps ,part b)](https://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.046/fall01/handouts/ps2sol.pdf)

Answer (score -1):

Answer to the second question is h = log<sub>d</sub>(n(d-1) + 1) - 1
So, h = log<sub>d</sub>(nd - n + 1) - 1

Comment: Why is this the answer? A formula with no explanation doesn't really help anyone.