# d-ary heapsort analysis

Tags: data-structures, runtime-analysis, sorting, heaps

I need to find a tight bound on the number of comparisons in a d-ary heapsort, in terms of `d` and `n` (the length of the array we want to sort).

Since inserting `n` items to a heap takes `O(n)` , and each delete-min takes `O(d log n/ log d)`, I was thinking the bound is `O(n d log n / log d)`. Am I right? If so, how do I prove that it is indeed a tight bound?

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried?  Where did you get that from?  What attempts at proving it have you made?  Have you read our reference questions, e.g., http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/23593/755?  We want to help you understand concepts, not do your exercise for you.

Comment: Related: [A d-ary heap problem from CLRS](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/6078/4911)

Comment: Note that $O(d \log n /  \log d) = O(\log n)$, as everything else is constant (independent of $n$).

Answer (score 1):

> Inserting $n$ items to a heap takes $\Theta(n)$.

You probably mean that "building" a heap takes $\Theta(n)$.

> Each `delete-min` takes $\Theta(d \lg n/ \lg d)$, I was thinking the bound is $\Theta(n d \lg n / \lg d)$.

I agree with you.

> How do I prove that it is indeed a tight bound?

How tight do you want to prove it is? Do you want to show that the worst-case running time of $d$-ary heap-sort is $\Omega(n d \lg n / \lg d)$? If so, I tend to think it is indeed tight.

For a hint, [this paper: The Analysis of Heapsort](ftp://ftp.cs.princeton.edu/techreports/1991/330.pdf) mentions that (in Abstract)

> The number of keys moved during $2$-ary heap-sort when sorting a random file of $n$ *distinct* elements is $n \lg n + O(n)$ in the worst case.

It even further proves that (Notice that it is for the ***best case***)

> Theorem 1 (Page 7): Heap-sort ($2$-ary) requires at least $\frac{1}{2} n \lg n- O(n)$ data moves for any heap composed of *distinct* keys.

Maybe you can adapt it to $d$-ary heap-sort.